# Finding duplicate values in dictionary and print Key of the duplicate element

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, compare, duplicates

What can be the **fastest** way to to check the duplicate values in the dictionary and print its key?

Dictionary `MyDict` which is having following values,

Key  **Value**

22     **100**

24     **200**

25     **100**

26     **300**

29     **200**

39     **400**

41     **500**

Example: key 22 and 25 have same values and  i need to print that 22 and 25 have duplicate values.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It depends.
If you have an ever changing dictionary and need to get that information only once, use this:

```
MyDict.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
```

However, if you have a dictionary that is more or less static and need to get this information more than once, you should not just save your data in a Dictionary but also in a `ILookup` with the value of the dictionary as the key and the key of the dictionary as the value:

```
var lookup = MyDict.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

To print the info, you can use the following code:

```
foreach(var item in lookup)
{
    var keys = item.Aggregate("", (s, v) => s+", "+v);
    var message = "The following keys have the value " + item.Key + ":" + keys;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Comment: Dictionary will be created only once when i will call one function and there will be no change in the dictionary in that particular call. Can you please tell how can i Print keys of the duplicate values..This dictionary thing is  new for me..Thanks.

Comment: @ Daniel: i think i have confused you. I need a message like "Following keys have duplicate values: 22 and 25". I could not understand how your code compares and finds duplicate value. When i used your code,It is just printing every key and value of the look up.

Comment: @Sangram: No it doesn't. It prints only those keys that have the same value. Please check again. However, for a short time there *was* code in my answer, that would return all keys. Maybe by some odd chance you tested this? Your code to create the lookup needs to look like this: `var lookup = MyDict.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);`. Note the `Where(...)` part at the end.

Comment: @ Daniel:yes. You are right.Its working now. There was some problem with the earlier code,in the Lookup. Its working now. Thanks a ton. I have one question. How did you compare 2 elements? by Using (x => x.Value, x => x.Key).Where(x => x.Count() > 1) ?? You must have seen Scott's answer. That's another correct answer. But can i say ur approach is faster ? i think so.

Comment: Scotts answer is the same as my first answer. He is just using the query syntax while I am using the method chains syntax. His version gets converted into my version by the compiler, so they are the same. The comparison is done automatically inside `ToLookup`.

Answer (score 6):

for a sample

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    dic.Add(1, 1);
    dic.Add(2, 4);
    dic.Add(3, 1);
    dic.Add(4, 2);

    var result = from p in dic
                 group p by p.Value into g
                 where g.Count() > 1
                 select g;


    foreach (var r in result)
    { 
        var sameValue = (from p in r 
                        select p.Key + "").ToArray();


        Console.WriteLine("{0} has the same value {1}:",
                          string.Join("," , sameValue) , r.Key);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```