# Which data structure to use for fast search? (C#)

Tags: data-structures, hash, tree, avl-tree

I need a efficient data structure for searching. Currently I am using a simple List from System.Collections.Generic until I find a good solution.

The user can add/remove strings at runtime by clicking on them in a list. But the main operation is searching because every time the user want's to see the list I need to check for every entry if the user already clicked on it before. The list may contain about 100-1000 entries of which the user can choose about 100. The list with the chosen strings will also be saved as a string array to disk and needs to be loaded again. So the data structure should be fast to rebuild from a string array if the array was saved in the correct order.

I thought about using an AVL tree. Is it a good solution? Or would hashing be possible (I don't know the strings that can be chosen at compile time)?

Comment: I think if your main focus is on searching then a hash map/table would be more beneficial. Especially if you are looking to store strings and only need say 100 entries or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using C# I would recommend using: [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). It will allow you to store strings in a Hash Map (which is a related to Java's `Map`). The benefit of storing strings in a `Dictionary` is similar to that of a hash table which will allow constant time of searching, inserting, and deleting. Should you want to check if there are duplicate values you can check here for more information: [Finding duplicate values in dictionary and print Key of the duplicate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172394/finding-duplicate-values-in-dictionary-and-print-key-of-the-duplicate-element).

Comment: A dictionary looks good but what would I store? I only got strings, so would I just save those as keys and set a default value like 0?

Comment: @Superwayne - There are several ways you could go about creating the `Dictionary`. You want each string to have its own key, that way when you want to see if that string is in your dictionary you only need to check the `Dictionary` at a certain value. Listing all strings at the default zero would not be a good idea as all strings would be associated with the value 0. You could store them as such `IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();`. This way your key is the string you are looking for and you are able to store that string in case you need it later.

Comment: @Superwayne - You can then see if your Dictionary already contains the string the user entered using the `ContainsKey()` method in C#. I hope this helps, if you need more information you can look here: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary