# C# checking if duplicate in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, duplicates

**This isn't a duplicate, since I'm using objects as key**

I'm trying to create a dictionary which checks if the object that's being inserted is a duplicate, and if it is, it'll increase it's value.
My dictionary looks like this:

```
Dictionary<Object, int> output = new Dictionary<Object, int>();
```

In this example, Object is the object I want to check if it's a duplicate. The integer stands for a 'weight' value, this is used further in my application.

How do I check if an object is a duplicate, and if it is how do I increase this integer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't insert duplicate keys into a dictionary. It will fail with "key already exists"

Comment: This is pretty much covered by [the examples in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) or any basic tutorial on how to use a dictionary.

Comment: Okay and how would I increase the int if it fails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in dictionary and print Key of the duplicate element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172394/finding-duplicate-values-in-dictionary-and-print-key-of-the-duplicate-element)

Comment: Dictionary<Object, int> output = new Dictionary<Object, int>();
            Object obj = new object();
            int weight = 0;
            if(output.ContainsKey(obj))
            {
                output.Add(Convert.ToInt32(obj) + 1, weight);
            }

Comment: why are you using type object ?  Surely something more specific is appropriate

Comment: Because I want the objects from a database. And if the object exists twice, I want to increase the weight

Comment: Well thank you for your input. I have values stored in a database table, and get these values and put them in objects. After that I want to use these objects in my code. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is efficient one. People often forget about TryGetValue.

```
Dictionary<Object, int> output = new Dictionary<Object, int>();
int count;
if(output.TryGetValue(keyObject, out count))
{
     output[keyObject] = count + 1;
}
else
{
     output.Add(keyObject, 1);
}
```

Object is reference type, so even if your objects have same values, they can reside at different positions in memory. For this to work with objects, you should override Equals and GetHashCode methods for your concrete class implementation. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Value {get;set;}

    public override int GetHashCode() { return Value.GetHashCode(); }
    public override bool Equals(object other){return ((MyClass)other).Value.Equals(Value); }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on objects though. I changed it to where the dictionary contains 2 ints, the id of the object and the weight and it works fine. Can this be altered where it still contains objects?

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as:

```
int currentCount = output.ContainsKey(obj) ? output[obj] : 0;
output[obj] = currentCount + 1; // Inserts if key not found and updates otherwise
```

Comment: This gets me an 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Method group'' error. Am I doing something wrong?