# Finding duplicate lists in dictionary and print Key of the duplicated list

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, collections, duplicates

I'm interested in finding the keys in a dictionary if there's an exact matching value list

Below is a dictionary where there are list of students associated to a class.

```
var studentsInClass = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

studentsInClass.Add("Maths", new List<string> { "James", "Bob", "Sophia" });
studentsInClass.Add("English", new List<string> { "James", "Bob", "Sophia", "Mel" });
studentsInClass.Add("History", new List<string> { "Hannah" });
studentsInClass.Add("Geography", new List<string> { "Paul", "Zack" });
studentsInClass.Add("Art", new List<string> { "Paul", "Zack" });
```

For example, I would like to see the classes/keys **Geography** and **Art** as **Paul** and **Zack** (and only those two) is in those two classes. While **James**, **Bob** and **Sophia** are both in **Math** and **English**, **Mel** is in **English** so it's not an exact match.

I have followed a similar question here [Finding duplicate values in dictionary and print Key of the duplicate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172394/finding-duplicate-values-in-dictionary-and-print-key-of-the-duplicate-element)

But I would think that this would not work on lists or reference types

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Does ordering matter?

Comment: hi- order does not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by a string which that is created by concatenating the items of the lists in your dictionary. With that, you can avoid the problem that you compare two lists which have the same items, but point to different references.

```
var groups = studentsInClass.GroupBy(x => string.Join("", x.Value)).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Here, you group and filter these groups if they have more than one item, which is Geography and Art in your example.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Up72sw

Note: The code above will consider the order of your students. If Geography was "Zack", "Paul", it would not recognize it as the same. If you want to ignore the order if your items, sort your items before joining them:

```
var groups = studentsInClass.GroupBy(x => string.Join("", x.Value.OrderBy(y => y))).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq could make this example a bit better, but since I guess this is an exercise for an introductionary course, I've done it with loops.

```cs
            var studentsInClass = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

            studentsInClass.Add("Maths", new List<string> { "James", "Bob", "Sophia" });
            studentsInClass.Add("English", new List<string> { "James", "Bob", "Sophia", "Mel" });
            studentsInClass.Add("History", new List<string> { "Hannah" });
            studentsInClass.Add("Geography", new List<string> { "Paul", "Zack" });
            studentsInClass.Add("Art", new List<string> { "Paul", "Zack" });

            var identicalClasses = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            /*iterate all key-value pairs in the just created dictionary*/
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry in studentsInClass)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry2 in studentsInClass)
                {
                    /* first we check if we're verifying a key that isn't the entry key itself.
                     * Secondly, we check if the list contains all elements in the second list.
                     * Finally, we make sure the lists are the same size.
                     */ 
                    if (entry.Key != entry2.Key && entry.Value.All(entry2.Value.Contains) && entry.Value.Count == entry2.Value.Count) //If order matters, you can use entry.Value.SequenceEqual(entry2.Value)
                    {
                        /*add the key-value pair to a dict which we can use somewhere else.*/
                        identicalClasses.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                        //Just to show the keys we've added to our identicalClasses list
                        Console.WriteLine("key = " + entry.Key);
                        //We need to break since we don't want to list the key multiple times should there be more than 2 identical classes.
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If ordering does matter then you can take advantage of [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?).

The most simplistic solution I can think of:

```
foreach(var lhs in studentsInClass)
    foreach(var rhs in studentsInClass)
    {
        if(lhs.Key == rhs.Key) continue;
        if(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(lhs.Value, rhs.Value))
            Console.WriteLine(lhs.Key + " + " + rhs.Key);
    }
```

This will print:

```
Geography + Art
Art + Geography
```